# node.js get relative to project/src path of file

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node.js project I use log4js and I want my logs to have name of the file where log record was added. So I use __filename but it gives me absolute path

```
var logger = log4js.getLogger(__filename)
```

So it gives me logs like this:

```
[1999-01-01 00:00:00] [DEBUG] /Users/whatever/myproject/src/services/users something happened
```

But I want the path to be relative to my project/src folder. Like this:

```
[1999-01-01 00:00:00] [DEBUG] services/users something happened
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use [`path.relative`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to):

```
var relativePath = path.relative(process.cwd(), someFilePath);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. But I decided to simply go with explicit log4js.getLogger('services/user') since using path needs using require('path')

Answer (score 1):

```
var root = '/Users/whatever/myproject/src/';

var filename = __filename.replace(root, '');
```

string `replace` will replace the first occurence so even if you have several times `root` pattern, it will be replaced only once.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`path.basename()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_basename_p_ext) with `__dirname` and `__filename` both:

```
var path = require('path');
var here = path.basename(__dirname) + '/' + path.basename(__filename, '.js');
```

Alternatively if you're fond of regular expressions, you could do something like:

```
var here = /\/([^/]+\/[^/]+)\.js$/.exec(__filename)[1];
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately it will only work for two levels, so in case I have something like 'services/external/api' it will not help